# I am trying to disable user from IDM tool to AD using OOTB connector, while disabling is giving error as LDAP: error code 20 - 0000207E:

Tags: active-directory, ldap, identitymanager

I am trying to disable user from IDM system to ad using OOTB connector , provisioning and update operation works fine but disable gives error as

> "Error while Delete operation for account-Test in AD - [LDAP: error
>   code 20 - 0000207E: AtrErr: DSID-031906FC, #1: 0: 0000207E:
>   DSID-031906FC, problem 1006 (ATT_OR_VALUE_EXISTS), data 0, Att 90008
>   (userAccountControl) ]"

I checked the error code 20 but still unable to figure out what needs to be changed. Please let me know if you have any idea on this.

Comment: Which IDM System? Most IDM Systems provide more details in some trace log.

Comment: Its Saviynt.Dont have server level access to check logs.I am giving the details of whatever I get from UI